# uniform distribution, probability

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

This is regarding the previously asked question: Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be random times for a company to complete two steps in a certain process. Say $T_1$ and $T_2$ are measured in days and they have the joint PDF that is uniform over the space $1 < t_1 < 10, 2 < t_2 < 6$, and $t_1 + 2t_2 < 14$. What is $P(T_1 + T_2 > 10)$?

Can anyone provide the working steps for me?

Comment: First step: Draw a careful picture.  Include the lines $t_1+2t_2=14$ and $t_1+t_2=10$.

Comment: Second step: Delete from your mind whatever negative thoughts you might have about unhelpful responses from people on this forum, and return to the First step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is find the area of the space allowed in your problem (depicted)

[image: Allowed space]

I'd then find the area of the space you're looking to find the probability of landing in, which means adding this inequality:

$$t_1 + t_2 > 10$$

Which looks like this:

[image: Interested space]

Divide the second area by that of the first, and you get your probability!

Comment: This is pretty much how I would go at it, except that since I'd be drawing the areas by hand rather than in software, my drawings would have the same scale for the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: thanks alot. It really helps alot :D